# Adobe Air: WindowedApplication

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

I am a beginner. I have developed a desktop application using Adobe Air Flash Builder. I am using a WindowedApplication Container that serves as the entry point for the Flex Application.

The problem:
I have a button whose event handler redirects me to a new window using the the addElement and NavigatorContent property. Here's the handler:

```
        public function startstudy_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var dTracker:Study = new Study();
            this.addElement(dTracker);
        }
```

Here's the NavigatorContent code:

```
        <s:NavigatorContent width="100%" height="100%" label="PRACTICE" icon="@Embed(source='assets/image.png')" toolTip="PRACTICE" id="navprac">
```

What's happening is that when I am redirected to the new window, the dimensions of the new window are not the same as those of the WindowedApplication. Infact, no matter whether I resize the WindowedApplication before clicking the button, the new window has the same exact dimensions everytime. I need the new window to be of the same size as the calling (WindowedApplication) window.

Is there a way around this? If not, then how can I make all the windows to be the same size from the start,that is, disable their resizing and set all windows to the size of the screen.

Comment: you need to show some code, what type is "this" and show some code about Study class,  you can try setting minWidth=maxWidth=width=myvalue; same for height

Comment: "this" is the current window (also the entry window for the application) which calls the "Study" window using the addElement function. The code is pretty big so I don't know which snippet should I share. Please can you specify which code (functionality) do you want? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your comments above, `Study` is of type `Window` in which case, when you invoke `new Study()` you are creating a new window. This window has a completely different set of height and width the the first window created when the `WindowedApplication` started.

To get around this you could explicitly state these properties:

```
var dTracker:Study = new Study();
dTracker.height = this.height;
dTracker.width = this.width;
dTracker.x = this.x;
dTracker.y = this.y;
```

Or you could change `Study` from being a window to something like `Group` or `Panel`, this would then add it to the current window rather than creating a new one